# Changing the id field to an _id field for the lowest tweet id

Tags: python, iteration, twitter

I am collecting tweets using a Python script and I want to store them in a MongoDB database.

I want to find out the lowest tweet id and for each tweet, I want to change the `id` field to an `_id` field.

Is it possible not having to iterate over all the tweets with a `for` loop in order to do these 2 things.

```
search_result = #search result from Twitter API

min_id = float('inf')

result = []
for tweet in search_result:
    if tweet['id'] < min_id:
        min_id = tweet['id']
    tweet['_id'] = tweet.pop('id')
    result.append(tweet)
```

Comment: As I said on your StackOverflow question, "Is there any way I optimize" is way too vague of a question. Do you want it to be faster, take less memory, be more maintainable, or some other metric? If it's speed you're worried about, which part is too slow? How much data do you have? How are you data stored?

Comment: `min_id` would likely decrease as you iterate through `search_result`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, because I want to find the lowest id

Comment: Why do you want to rename "id" to "_id"? Are you using this to find out which tweets you have already "processed"?

Comment: Because Google tells us that MongoDB uses `_id` as the primary key for documents.  Without the unnecessary `result`/`result.append` this is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three parts to your questions: 1) find lowest tweet ID and 2) assign `id:` to `_id` 3) can (1) and (2) be done without iterating over the list.

To answer (3) first, (1) definitely can be done without iteration, but I am unaware of how to do (2) without iteration.

**(1) Lowest Tweet ID**
The sort function is great for this. [This question has more on sorting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403421/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-in-python-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-objects) To create a new list with the lowest id in the first position:

```
results = sorted(search_results, key=lambda x: x.id)
```

To do the same thing replacing the list:

```
search_results.sort(search_results, key=lambda x: x.id)
```

Simply access the "0"th result in the list and you have your lowest tweet id.

**2) Assign `id:` to `_id`**

Perhaps someone can answer this better, but the best way I know of is how you've done it:

```
for tweet in search_results:
    tweet['_id'] = tweet.pop('id')
```

Your final code would look something like:

```
search_result = #search result from Twitter API
results = sorted(search_results, key=lambda x: x.id)
min_id = results[0]['id']
for tweet in search_results:
    tweet['_id'] = tweet.pop('id')
```

Comment: So using `sort` instead of iterating through the list would not gain me anything, because I still have to iterate through the list to change the `id` field.

Comment: `sort` likely has a performance increase as it only accesses the elements in the array once, while iterating through accesses each element at least once on top of checking that element against a variable, and assign several of those to that variable.

Comment: Do you mean `sorted` instead of `sort`? I only know of the builtin `sorted` and `list.sort`.

Comment: Your right @sebix. I corrected the error.

Comment: So now it's `n*log(n)`, before it was linear, that's not an improvement. And an empty result is not handled.

Comment: @ferada I think the sorting is redundant, as `min` also works. Then it's `2*n`, which should be very near to your for-loop.